# Why does this anonymous type Linq expression work?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, linq, anonymous-types

I was looking for a code snippet that returns the indices of the top N elements given an array of floats. I found the following code and it works, but I have no idea why:

```
        int[] indexArray = floatArray
               .Select((value, index) => new { value, index })
               .OrderByDesc(item => item.value)
               .Take(N)
               .Select(item => item.index)
               .ToArray();
```

How does the program know that the first property of the anonymous type is the value of the float element and the second property is its index? I mean why not the opposite? And why the index at all?

Comment: Are you asking why Select passes the value and the index? Because that's what the person who wrote it intended it to do. It has an overload that passes just the value to the selector and another that passes the value and the index. See the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534869(v=vs.100).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does the program know that the first property of the anonymous type is the value of the float element and the second property is its index?

It is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.110).aspx)

> selector Type: `System.Func<TSource, Int32, TResult>`
>
> A transform function to apply to each source element; **the second
>   parameter of the function represents the index** of the source element.

```
(value, index) => new { value, index }
```

is a lambda expression. It takes two arguments,and returns a result. first parameter type is the type of the element in your collection and second one is an integer which is the index. The names don't matter here, you can say `(x,y) => new { x , y }` it's the same thing, the important thing is the order of your arguments. You can think this expression as a syntactic sugar for a method like this:

```
public ResultType MyMethod(MyType value, int index)
{

}
```

If you see this syntax for the first time you should definitely look at the documentation:

- [Lambda Expressions (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)

Comment: This explained a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `Select` extension method has various overloads, and the one you're using, the one that takes a function taking two arguments ([this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)), calls that function with the first argument being the value, and the second argument being the index. The language knows nothing of this, it's simply specified like that in the libraries. It could equally have been defined in the opposite order.

> *selector*
>
> Type: System.Func<TSource, Int32, TResult>
> A transform function to apply to each source element; the second parameter of the function represents the index of the source element.

Comment: I still don't understand because if I write it like this:
    floatArray.Select((x, y) => new {x, y})
it still works.
So how come the program knows that the properties I am talking about are the value of the element and its index?

Comment: @AhmedAshour Oh, heh, that's not what I got from your question at all. Let me edit.